# How to rectify Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError error in laravel-6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

i am trying to create a notes(with title and body) that should be store in database for that i write some api (only valid user can able to create notes based on the token),i am able to get the token when successfully logged in , When i try to create a note it's throwing some error ,How to rectify that error please help me to fix this issue...

`Error`

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Class &#039;Notes&#039; not found in file /home/payarc/Desktop/newLaravel/app/Http/Controllers/NotesController.php on line 20
```

`NotesController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Notes;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class NotesController extends Controller
{
    public function create_Note(Request $request)
    {
        $note=new Notes();
        
        $note->title=$request->input('title');
        $note->body=$request->input('body'); 
        $note->user_id = Auth()->id();         
        $note->save();
        return $note;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
use Notes;
```

with full path

```
use App\Models\Notes;
```

Answer (score -1):

You simply use for creating object of notes model like this

```
$note=new AppNotes();
```